# He is asked me to dinner. Is the sentence right?

Tags: past-participles, present-participles, participles

He is asked me to dinner. 
He is asking me to dinner.

The first sentence come from a native speaker of English.
Is it correct？
What is the difference between the meaning what it expressed and the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is not correct. We can use the past tense and say "he has asked me to dinner". The second sentence means "he is, at this moment, asking me to dinner".

Comment: We could also make the first sentence correct by dropping "is" entirely, which results in a simpler form of the past tense: "he asked me to dinner".  The meaning is, of course, slightly different that way.